# To align the Datepicker button and calender of Datepicker dynamically through code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, styles, uielement

My requirement is to align the `DatePicker` button and calender to the extreme right in the `DatePicker` control (only through code behind). I am creating a `DatePicker` control which is dynamically generated if the data type is date.

Here's the present code:

```
if (type.ToLower() == "date")
{
  control = new DatePicker();

  (control as DatePicker).Name = name;
  (control as DatePicker).FontSize = 24;
  (control as DatePicker).FontWeight = FontWeights.Light;
  (control as DatePicker).MinWidth = 450;
  (control as DatePicker).HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
  (control as DatePicker).VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
}
```

Just wanted to know, What extra i should write to keep the `DatePicker` button at the right such that 
the calender also should open at the right i.e to the bottom of the `DatePicker` button.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property of `Left`. If you avoid doing this, the calendar button will end up to in the right edge of the `TextBox`.

If you then want the calendar to show up under the button, you could handle the `Loaded` event of the `DatePicker` and set the `PlacementTarget` property of the `Popup` in the template:

```
(control as DatePicker).FontSize = 24;
(control as DatePicker).FontWeight = FontWeights.Light;
(control as DatePicker).MinWidth = 450;
(control as DatePicker).VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
(control as DatePicker).Loaded += (ss, ee) =>
{
    DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)ss;
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup = dp.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", dp) as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup;
    Button button = dp.Template.FindName("PART_Button", dp) as Button;
    if (popup != null && button != null)
        popup.PlacementTarget = button;
};
```

Comment: Just wanted to know from you, How can i make the button (PART_Button) look larger. I tried increasing the height by setting button.Height but it did not worked out.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.